# Database Design for multiple tables of same type

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I have a situation where I would like to store about a terabyte of information in a database format to support query. I am not experienced when it comes to database design, which is partially why I would like to ask on how to do this properly.

We have a test suite which produces sets of information fields for each state update. About 400 individual 64-bit fields of information for each state update, and we'd like to keep around 400 Million information ticks. The problem is that we're receiving information update from around 1600 machines.

A useful(for us) database query, would be in the format of "Have I seen this field have value X, while 5 state updates earlier, the same field had value Y?"

My initial understanding was to implement this in a database, where each state update was stored sequencially (about 250k states per machine). However this would generate 1600 identical tables, with around 250k rows per table.

Is there some design methodology that I don't understand quite yet? I feel like having 1600 tables is a desirable trait, because that feels like something that queries could run in parallel on ?

To summarize : Given a situation where multiple identical machines are running slightly different tests, and I have to store the last 250k - 1M state ticks they have had, how should I design the database ? My current idea is to create a table per test, where each row represents a state at time T, T+1, T+2 etc.

Is this optimal? Or is there a better approach than designing it like this? How long will my queries take for 1500-3000 tables of about 250k-1M entries each (since I want to query the entire dataset?) Can I get better results using a different approach ?

1500 tests, 400 64bit variables stored per state tick. 250k to 1M state ticks per test, and I would like to be able to store and query this entire dataset quickly and efficiently. What is the best approach?

Comment: Your question is not clear for me.

Comment: Having 1600 tables/collections does not make sense. Reads should always be possible in parallel. And since the difference can be expressed as a field or combination of fields, I would put all data sets into the same collection.

Comment: How would I distinguish between when one test ends and the next one begins if I keep everything in one huge table? Will there be no degradation of performance in keeping one huge table? And how do I stop it from giving me queries that overlap tests? I don't want it to give me a result for a query that spans cross-tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would always prefer single table/collection, when each test step should be identified by test ID and step ID. For example:

**MySQL (denormalized)**

steps

```
id  test        step        data
1   "Host_Test" "Step01"    [serialized data]
```

**MySQL (normalized (partially))**

steps

```
id  test        step
1   "Host_Test" "Step01"
```

stepdetails

```
step_id data_key    data_value
1       "key"       "value"
```

**MongoDB**

```
{
    _id : "1",
    test : "Host_Test",
    step : "Step01",
    data : {
        key1 : value1,
        key2 : value2
    }
}
```

Then you can, of course, identify data per test by test identifier.

If you are testing in memory, storing data to database/disc will always be your main weak point. Writing to one big table/collection won't be the main point.

Comment: Is there any method to make this faster. The reality is for each query, I'm interested in seeing which test satisfied the conditions, and how many tests in total satisfy each condition

Comment: Configure database server to work as much as possible just in memory (defer disk operations). Try to look on redis: http://redis.io/.